# How can I change the decimal comma to point in c# with DisplayFormat?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have to change the decimal comma to a point without changing the culture settings.
This is the only thing I found, but it doesn't change anything:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:$###.###}")]
public double Number { get; set; }
```

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:$###,###}")]
public double Number { get; set; }
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: That's determined by the culture not the format string.  In the format string comma is always a thousandth place separator and period is always a decimal separator and the culture will determine the actual characters used for each.

Comment: As @juharr already mentioned this should be done by culture settings, but you already specified that culture shouldn't be used. Your only bet is to manually replace the comma with a point after your number was converted to a string: `number.Replace(",", ".")`

Comment: Also if you display a number in a US format to someone in Europe or vice versa they will be confused.

Answer (score 0):

As @juharr already mentioned this should be done by culture settings, but you already specified that culture shouldn't be used.

Your only bet is to manually replace the comma with a point after your number was converted to a string: `number.Replace(",", ".")`.

You could also add another Property like "NumberAsCurrencyString" or anything like that, that returns a formatted string determined by culture just for this case. All other culture settings inside your project or server won't be changed.

```cs
//using required for CultureInfo
using System.Globalization;

public NumberAsCurrencyString => Number.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: With "C0" I get an Integer number in a currency format instead of a decimal number.
Sorry, I messed up the code a bit, it is fixed now.

Comment: @Tobi well, your Number property was previously an integer value, so and your format is not showing any decimal digits. Beside of that you're still free to use any format you like (e.g. 'C2' adds 2 decimal digits), also your initial one works: `ToString("$###,###", CultureInfo...)`

Answer (score -1):

You can try it, this work for me:

```
string.Replace(".",",");
```

That it's the fastest you can try, it doesn't change the culture

Comment: 1) you're not capturing the result of string.Replace, 2) the use of a displayformat attribute suggests that there's no opportunity to change the actual displayed value before it's displayed